# I am creating sequelize query with nested logical operators

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize, sequelize-hooks

I am creating the nested logical operator or and logical operator and, but it gives different results.

```
const whereClaues = {
              DailyMarketId: dailyMarket.id,
              TransactionType: TransactionType.Bid,
            };
            if (bidType == BidType.OPEN) {
              whereClaues.BidType = { [Op.in]: [BidType.OPEN, BidType.CLOSE] };
            } else {
              whereClaues[Op.or] = [
                { BidType: BidType.CLOSE },
                {
                  BidType: BidType.OPEN,
                  GameId: {
                    [Op.in]: gameIds,
                  },
                },
              ];
            }
```

this is the condition in where clause and I am using it in get all query as below:

```
await models.BidTransaction.findAll({
                where: whereClaues,
                attributes: [
                  "UserId",
                  [Sequelize.fn("sum", Sequelize.col("Coins")), "BidAmount"],
                ],
                group: ["UserId"],
              })
```

console.log(whereclause)

```
// Error
// {
//   DailyMarketId: 193,
//   IsActive: true,
//   IsWin: true,
//   TransactionType: 'Win',
//   Open: [ { BidType: 'Close' }, { BidType: 'Open', GameId: [Object] } ]
// }

// Correct
// {
//   DailyMarketId: 193,
//   IsActive: true,
//   IsWin: true,
//   TransactionType: 'Win',
//   [Symbol(or)]: [ { BidType: 'Close' }, { BidType: 'Open', GameId: [Object] } ]
// }
```

getting these 2 response. Why ai am getting this 2 different response and from where I get Open field ?